# AWS Application Load Balancer not accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I have created an AWS load balancer connected to a VPC with subnets that have routing tables with internet gateway like that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgTNa.png)

I've got the subnets having routing table with an internet gateway like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOahS.png)

I've got the security groups open on all ports for all ips.

Still I cannot access my load balancer at income-api-loadbalancer-1730847403.eu-north-1.elb.amazonaws.com

```
% ping income-api-loadbalancer-1730847403.eu-north-1.elb.amazonaws.com
PING income-api-loadbalancer-1730847403.eu-north-1.elb.amazonaws.com (51.21.31.9): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
```

`telnet` an `nc` to port 80 to 51.21.31.9 (the ip address of the domain name give above) are timing out

```
% nc -v 51.21.31.9 80
nc: connectx to 51.21.31.9 port 80 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out
```

Looks like I cannot even access the host where my loadbalancer is suposed to sit even though the loadbalancer is in an active state.

Aany clues what could be the problem?

I tried experimenting with different permissions in the security groups in order to at least be able to see the Load balancer at port 80 or 443.

Tried allowing all trafic on the ACL of the VPC:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lzkC.png)

Expecting this is locking the trafic but it didn't work.

Comment: The AWS Load Balancers do not respond to ping/ICMP requests, and may not respond to telnet requests on differnet ports other than those configured in the listener.

So I'd check the load balancer listener for the necessary protocol and port that you need to forward the traffic to the correct target group, as well as the good health of your target group.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I have a listener at port 80 (originally port 443 but changed for the sake of experiments) and the target group is heltly and accesible even trough internet right now. The target group servers are working on port 8080 and is healthy. Is there any way to debug if requests are hittiing at all the Application Load Balancer and potential problems on the way to target group?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem following the sugestion in this post: [AWS Application Load Balancer to EC2 Node over HTTPS not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73545203/aws-application-load-balancer-to-ec2-node-over-https-not-responding)

In a nutshel do not use the default security group for the load balancer but add you own.

This is very confusing though as the default security group has everything open for incoming trafic...